# Show compiler where to find a specific type definition file

Tags: typescript

I'm using [uhtml](https://github.com/WebReflection/uhtml) in my project. It includes a type definition file in `./node_modules/uhtml/types/index.d.ts`. I can't figure out how to tell `tsc` to find it.

I can make it work by copying `./node_modules/uhtml/types` to my `./types/uhtml/` but I'd rather refer directly to the file in `./node_modules/uhtml/types`.

I've tried variations on `///<reference` to no avail.

I'd like a way to say "use this specific file for uhtml".

Here is a minimal example of what I'm doing. With this configuration, lsp flags the import of uhtml as not having a type definitions file.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "uhtml-path",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "uhtml": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

example.js

```
import { html } from "uhtml";
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "checkJs": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "WebWorker"]
  }
}
```

Comment: They should be picked up automatically when you import: https://github.com/WebReflection/uhtml/blob/5ef2bb793a7ca6bdda3b2085561e733877ab2ee0/package.json#L37-L41

Comment: I agree but they are not.

Comment: Could you give a [mre], then? Maybe you need [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots), but you shouldn't.

Comment: What version of Node.js do you use? If it  is too old, it does not read the `modules` property of `package.json` and expects the path to the types file to be in the `types` property.

Comment: Node is 20.9.0.

Comment: Couldn't replicate - only issue WebStorm has is that the import's unused. It's picking up the correct type for `html`, from `./node_modules/uhtml/types/index.d.ts`.

Comment: vscode and my neovim lsp both flag it.

Comment: Changing moduleResolution to "bundler" seems to fix it in my minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `moduleResolution` from `node` to `bundler` in the `jsconfig.json` file fixed it for me.